# How to save figure in matplotlib ajusted to the object size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, figure, savefig

Hello everyone I am trying to save the figures from matplotlib. It saves with blank spaces around the figure, I mean It adds space, It is no saved with ajusted object size. It is very easy to edit them in Inkscape (I make that in this software), but  that's not nice when there are more than 50 figures.
I do that because in beamer slides a figure with extra space occupies a lot of space, because of the sheet it is very small.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use constrained layout. There are some possibilities:

`plt.figure` function

```
# 3.5.3 and 3.6
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), layout="constrained")
fig.add_subplot()
plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

`plt.subplots` function

```
# 3.5.3 and 3.6
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6), layout="constrained")
ax.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

Set layout on Figure object, after its creation:

```
# 3.5.3
fig.set_constrained_layout(True)

# 3.6
fig.set_layout_engine("constrained")
```

More info:

> https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-constrainedlayout-guide-py